# Making Buttons Appear and Disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://www.jsfiddle.net/Akmedrah/1cf6obpu/

Here is a fiddle of a picture button 'scroller' that I have. It is crappy but what I am really trying to figure out is the easiest way to make the arrow buttons that move the pictures right or left fade in and out when at the end of the order of pictures.

I was thinking of a java script function that essential knew the total number, something like this (I have no idea what i'm doing when it comes to JS but here is the best of what I guess it would look like):

```
function fadeinout(){
  var total = 2; //because two in fiddle example, but theoretical could have hundreds
  var current = //somehow get the current image based off id or class or some other identifier, or file name.
  if (current < 2) { //set up so i can expand??? maybe?
    document.getElementById("left-arrow").style.display = "true";
    document.getElementById("right-arrow").style.display = "true";
    }
  if (current == 1) {
    document.getElementById("left-arrow").style.display = "false";
    }
  if (current == 2) {
    document.getElementById("right-arrow").style.display = "false";
    }
  }
```

I just want to know if I am headed in the right direction or if I am making this way to complicated. Thanks!

Comment: `if 1<curent<2 {`, well you need to fix several syntax issues first.

Comment: Like I said i have no idea what I am doing with Java Script and am looking for some pointers or examples of how its done and a little input on if this is the easiest way to do it. I am not looking for someone to write the answer for me, I am looking to learn from those who have more skill than I.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Where can i find the proper way to do the Syntax?

Comment: I guess the basis of the solution should be a loop:  your current index, let's call that i will increase every step of the loop,  start counting from 0= for ( i=0; i < images.length; i++)  then. if (i=0 ) select the left arrow with and hide() it. If i=images.length  select the right arrow and hide it. The

Comment: @AngelPolitis Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Albert-JanStevens so you are saying that on the page load it would be set at one and every time you click a button it adds to "i" and then the if statements adjust things based off the current value of "I"?

Comment: The fiddle already does most of this. It has a jquery selector to get the total length  $("#containerms ul li") and use a variable i to hold the index. If I wanted to learn  javascript now, I would read some of eloquent javascript. [link](http://eloquentjavascript.net/)

Comment: Roger that thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Tou can use jquery for this

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_id

```
$("#left-arrow").hide();
$("#left-arrow").show();
```

You can also use the following to toogle show and hide

```
$("#left-arrow").toggle();
```

To check if an elemnent is visible or not you can use this:

```
$("#left-arrow").is(":visible")
```